# How to keep form input with the same function in 2 different pages

Tags: django, forms

Guys i am new to django and want to learn how to keep the same entry field in 2

different pages.

In `forms.py`:

```
class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm):
        name = forms.CharField(max_length=150)

        class Meta:
            model = Student
            fields = ['name',]
```

In `main.html` i have :

```
<form method="POST" >
              {% csrf_token %}
              {{ form}}
              <button class = "btn btn-primary" type="submit">OK</button> 

</form>
```

In `views.py`

```
def studinfo(request):
    form = StudentForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            form1 = form.save(commit=False)
            name = form1.name
            background=Student.objects.get(stud_name=name)

            context={'profile':background ,}

            return render(request, 'main/stud_info.html', context)

    return render(request, 'main/main.html', context={'form':form})
```

after submitting the form it is directed to `stud_info.html` where the results are shown based on the input value from the form on `main.html`.

My question is how i can keep the form input in `stud_info.html` page with the same function as in `main.html` so that i do not have to return to `main.html` page to look for a new value?

So far i tried simply copying the `main.html` form into `stud_info.html` how it only displays `OK` butoon and nothing.

I would appreciate any help and guidance in finding the solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**`session`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/sessions/) here. For example:

```
def studinfo(request):
    form = StudentForm(request.POST or None, initial={'name':request.session.get('student_name', None)})
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            form1 = form.save(commit=False)
            name = form1.name
            request.session['student_name'] = name
            background=Student.objects.get(stud_name=name)
            context={'profile':background ,}
            return render(request, 'main/stud_info.html', context)
    return render(request, 'main/main.html', context={'form':form})
```

One thing to mention here is that, as you are not updating anything in Database, it is better to use `GET` method instead of `POST`. Because by definition, GET methods are idempotent.

### Update

After carefully reading the problem, I think you can reuse `main.html` to show results and student info. Here is an example, based on get request:

```
def studinfo(request):
    form = StudentForm()
    name = request.GET.get('name', None)
    background = None
    if name:
       background=Student.objects.get(stud_name=name)

    context={'profile':background , 'form': form} 
    return render(request, 'main/main.html', context=context)

# main.html

<form method="GET" >
     {{ form}}
     <button class = "btn btn-primary" type="submit">OK</button> 
</form>
{% if profile %}
   {{ profile.name }}
{% endif %}
```

#### Alternative solution

Another solution is to send form through context when rendering `main/stud_info.html`.

```
def studinfo(request):
    form = StudentForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            form1 = form.save(commit=False)
            name = form1.name
            background=Student.objects.get(stud_name=name)

            context={'profile':background , 'form': StudentForm()}  #<-- Updated here

            return render(request, 'main/stud_info.html', context)

return render(request, 'main/main.html', context={'form':form})
```

And add the form related html files in `main/stud_info.html`

Answer (score 0):

**1- using localstorage:**

after clicking on `OK` button, save form data in localstorage with this javascript function:

```
localStorage.setItem('key', 'value')
```

and in `stud_info` page get stored data from localstorage with this:

```
localStorage.getItem('key')
```

---

**2- using database:**

if you save form data in the database after clicking on `OK` button

it is better to get that data from the database in `stud_info` page

Answer (score 0):

in student/main.html where you want.
    `{% include 'student/snippets/form.html' with form=form %}`

and in student/snippets folder create `form.html` with your form.

```
<form method="POST" >
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form}}
<button class = "btn btn-primary" type="submit">OK</button> 
</form>
```